# adverb "to" at the end of statements

Tags: adverbs

Could anybody explain me why this adverb places sometimes to the final of statements? What does it mean? Why is this there? Is this adverb a kind of grammatical particle? I can´t understand!:

Example: He pulled the door to.

It is supposed that this sentence means "He closed the door".

Comment: Did you confuse *to* with *too*?

Comment: The sentence is fine (@CinCout please note) It's a verbal idiom where "to" means _just not completely closed_. "To" is an intransitive preposition here - one which does not have an object complement. As for being a particle, it's borderline - it all depends on whether _?He pulled to the door is acceptable_.